# Can I use Panels context keywords in PHP functions?

Tags: 7, panels

I'm using the privatemsg module and I would like to display the number of unread messages a user has on his/her profile page.  I attempted to use %user, which is the context keyword for the user currently being viewed.

According to the privatemsg API documentation, the function for this is [privatemsg_unread_count()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_unread_count/7-1).  I tried calling the function like this:

`privatemsg_unread_count("%user");`

But I get an error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in privatemsg_unread_count()`

The function takes an account argument, which as far as I can tell (I'm not very skilled in PHP) is an array that stores the values for a given user.  Am I going the wrong way with trying to use the context keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use Panels context keywords in PHP functions.

My mistake was that %user does not return a user object.  However, context keywords can be used like this:

`$account = user_load(%user:uid);`

Here, the context keyword `%user:uid` will successfully evaluate to the ID of the user currently being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function without any argument and it will return the unread message count for the current user.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the context keyword %user is the user currently being viewed, not the currently logged in user.

Comment: You mean you want to show unread messages count of user a to the currently logged-in user b? Really?

Comment: Yes, in this particular case.